# Port forwarding ASUS RT-N66U

Tags: networking, router, port-forwarding, port

This issue is driving me crazy. I used to port forward in less than a minute. Now i can not open any port. Every port i open and listen to i get the result **Reason: Connection timed out**. In canyouseeme.org

I think the issue happened after i upgraded to the latest firmware.

Router ASUS RT-N66U 
Firmware Version:3.0.0.4.380_3831
IP: 192.168.0.1

Local ip to portforward to: 192.168.0.30

Modem:
 Manufacturer:FiberHome;
ProductClass:04;
SerialNumber:FHTT-00668899;
IP:192.168.1.1;

Added port forward to the IP 192.168.0.30

If i don't add the port forward through the modem then canyouseeme.org will give me Connection refused as reason. After adding it however the error will be connection timed out. But if i remove the port forwarding from ASUS it is still the same issue connection timed out.

So i am guessing the issue is in ASUS router.

Does anyone have a solution here?

Have tried almost everything. DMZ disable firewall UPNP etc. Still can not open the port.

I cannot get back to other firmwares only 1 worked but didnt solve the issue. I have tried many other lower firmwares but they just gave me error a msgbox

**To comply with regulatory amendments, we have modified our certification rule to ensure better firmware quality. This version is not compatible with all previously released ASUS firmware and uncertified third party firmware. Please check our official websites for the certified firmware.**

I am out of solutions.

Comment: You should try downgrading your firmware to version you were using

Comment: I already did that. But i dont call the number anymore. Tried lots of them but still only 1 has accepted but didnt fix the issue. Others did not work and gave me error on updating like transmission error or this msgbox

Comment: To comply with regulatory amendments, we have modified our certification rule to ensure better firmware quality. This version is not compatible with all previously released ASUS firmware and uncertified third party firmware. Please check our official websites for the certified firmware.

Comment: Update your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright so this is solved by Factory reset the Router.

Comment: Please Accept - You can answer your own questions and "accept" it as the answer that worked, this gives the site a working answer for this question should anybody have the same problem, you can also add more detail to the question giving a broader base for searches of similar questions, thankyou